# Best Windows ACL changes to make a file readable only by owner?

Tags: java, c++, windows, acl

I'm working on a client that gets a credential from a server and stores it in a file.  I'd like to a) make the file readable only by the owner and b) check before subsequent use that the file is readable only by the owner.

This is trivial on Linux.  My problem is with Windows.

Should I delete all the ACEs other than the owner's that grant read permission?  Or just delete all ACEs other than the owner's?

Or is it sufficient to add "deny" ACEs for the group and "Everyone"?

Or some third way?

I'm aware that a file can have inherited access rights but I'm not sure how to detect that and deauthorize everyone but the owner.

If it's relevant, the application that creates the file is in Java and the application that uses the file is in C++.

Comment: You definitely don't want to add a deny ACE for Everyone.  Since deny entries take precedence, you'd be blocking the user's access.  I'd recommend that you assign a brand new ACL containing only the one ACE.  When assigning this ACL to the file, indicate that permission inheritance should be disabled.  In C++ you'd use SetNamedSecurityInfo and pass the PROTECTED_DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION flag; hopefully Java has some equivalent.

Comment: Many thanks! How would you handle the reading client's problem: how to look at the ACL and determine if the file is readable only by owner?

Comment: That's more complicated, but in most cases you can simplify it by asserting not that "the file must be readable only by the owner" but that "the file must have the same permissions I originally assigned it".  That is, you check that there is exactly one ACE and that the ACE has the correct security principal.  You might also like to check that the right user still owns the file.  (Make sure these requirements are well documented or sysadmins will get very cross!)